# HTML not updating when rendering tubostream in Rails 7 for a custom controller method

Tags: error-handling, customization, server-side-rendering, ruby-on-rails-7, hotwire-rails

I am running Rails 7.0.4 and attempting to use turboframe/tubostream with a customer controller. I am trying to add an error message to the screen when the field from the form is not updated. The custom controller update method is triggered by a stimulus function when the user clicks out of a form field. The controller methods works in that the controller receives that data and the database is updated, however the changes to the page never occur.

I do not receive any errors in my development log. In fact I think what I'm seeing is what I *think* should likely be seeing - that it's rendering the turbostream and the partial referenced in the turbostream file. One thing I'm wondering though is why it says it's rendering the turbostream file twice:

```
20:55:37 web.1    |   TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
20:55:37 web.1    |   ↳ app/controllers/organization_controller.rb:34:in `api_update'
20:55:37 web.1    |   Rendering organization/organization_edit_form_error.turbo_stream.erb
20:55:37 web.1    |   Rendered organization/_error.html.erb (Duration: 0.5ms | Allocations: 134)
20:55:37 web.1    |   Rendered organization/organization_edit_form_error.turbo_stream.erb (Duration: 0.9ms | Allocations: 272)
20:55:37 web.1    | Completed 200 OK in 37ms (Views: 1.6ms | ActiveRecord: 4.0ms | Allocations: 10991)
```

In my Network tab in my developer console, I see this which is also what I believe I should be seeing:

```
<turbo-stream action="replace" target="organization_715728df-0095-4dae-b2c4-9b6911003bfd_error"><template>    test
    <div role="alert">
      Could not edit organization due to the following issues:
      <ul>
          <li>Website is not a valid URL</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</template></turbo-stream>
```

The concerned files that I'm working with:

controllers/organization_controller.rb (abbreviated)

```
  class OrganizationController < ApplicationController
    def api_update
      if organization.update(api_organization_params)
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { render :edit, organization: @organization }
        end
      else
        respond_to do |format|
          format.turbo_stream { render :organization_edit_form_error }
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

/views/organization/edit.html.erb

```
<div data-controller="organizations" class="mt-10">

    <%= turbo_frame_tag "#{dom_id(@organization)}_error" do %>
      <%= render partial: 'error', organization: @organization %>
    <% end %>

    <%= render 'form', organization: @organization %>
</div>
```

/views/organization/organization_edit_form_error.turbo_stream.erb

```
<%= turbo_stream.replace "#{dom_id(@organization)}_error", partial: "error", organization: @organization %>
```

/views/organization/_error.html.erb

```
  <% if @organization.errors.any? %>
    <div role="alert">
      Could not edit organization due to the following issues:
      <ul>
        <% @organization.errors.each do |error| %>
          <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

I tried adding a test output into the `_error.html.erb` partial within the `if @organization.errors.any?` block and seeing if the @organization is actually present and contains errors. It is indeed outputting to the Organization errors as expected in my development logs as expected.

I also tried a few different patterns of implementing turbostream from tutorials I saw. In particular, I tried just replacing the element without a turboform wrapper which was of course unsuccessful. I also tried adding the format.html to the respond_to block in my controller since I noticed that many implementations used this, however I'm assuming it's as a fallback.

I am quite new to turbostreams/turboforms and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: On your edit page, try putting the form inside the `turbo_frame_tag`. Another small thing: in your log, you say the turbostream file is rendered twice, but it isn't. First it's `Rendering`, then it's `Rendered`.

Comment: is there some confusion between `organization` and `@organization` in the controller?

Comment: These are excellent considerations so thank you for sharing these ideas. I did try these and they didn't appear to be the issue. I've been re-reading some material (https://www.hotrails.dev/turbo-rails/turbo-drive) and I'm wondering if it's because I'm already using an AJAX request to submit the form rather than the HTML request. The event that is firing is also happening on blur (ie. on click outside of a field) rather than on click.

With these considerations, I'm wondering if turbo is the right choice still or if I should abandon it and build something entirely using Stimulus.

Comment: No, sorry @fatfrog I moved on and used Stimulus.